# Wha functionalities does "Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)" provide?

Tags: pci-express, computer-architecture, intel

I'm setting up libvirt powered virtual machine for Windows10, on my Debian host, with passthrough-ed NVIDIA GPU. Everything goes well until I want to passthrough a USBHUB into the VM for convenience and found it impossible to passthrough a HUB directly.

The solution I come up with simply is: passthrough the whole PCIE XHCI controller into VM, instead of just a HUB running over USB protocol stack.

But on my platform, the `USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)` and `Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)` are in the same IOMMU group so, they must be passthrough-ed together.

I'm already tried that and find USB inside VM works without any issue, but I'm afraid if anything will happen because "Thermal Subsystem" is disabled now.

Tried searching but only find things like 'Unknown Device named “PCI data acquisition and signal processing controller” in Device Manager', no one even mention what it really is...

I want to know: What is this PCIe device? What functionalities does it provide? What will happen if I disabled that device on the host system?

Comment: Here's the [datasheet](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/332690/332690_SKL%20PCH%20EDS%20H%20Book_rev007_PUBLIC.pdf) of the chipset you're asking about. It does describe at least some of the functionalities.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks for the resource. Meanwhile I found the device is using `intel_pch_thermal` kernel driver, where I can investigate into

Comment: (thumbs up emoji)